# joining arrays, preserving different value, pick one if same. with php

Tags: php, arrays, logic

lets say from zero to more is important level of the value

```
  # very imporant
  0 =>
    array
      'index' => string 'helloworld:Index' (length=16)
      404 => string 'helloworld:Missinga' (length=19)
      503 => string 'helloworld:Offline' (length=18)
      'nojs' => string 'helloworld:Nojs' (length=15)
      'blog' => string 'helloworld:blog' (length=15)
  # important
  1 => 
    array
      'index' => string 'helloworld:Index' (length=16)
      404 => string 'helloworld:Missingb' (length=19)
      503 => string 'helloworld:Offline' (length=18)
      'nojs' => string 'helloworld:Nojs' (length=15)
      'blogb' => string 'helloworld:blog' (length=15)
  # not that important
  2 => 
    array
      'index' => string 'helloworld:Index' (length=16)
      404 => string 'helloworld:Missingc' (length=19)
      503 => string 'helloworld:Offline' (length=18)
      'nojs' => string 'helloworld:Nojs' (length=15)
       'more' => string 'helloworld:Nojs' (length=15)
  # so on
```

join them into one array to something like this

```
    array
      'index' => string 'helloworld:Index' (length=16) # from 0 ( others same key )
      404 => string 'helloworld:Missinga' (length=19)  # from 0 ( others same key )
      503 => string 'helloworld:Offline' (length=18)   # from 0 ( others same key )
      'nojs' => string 'helloworld:Nojs' (length=15)   # from 0 ( others same key )
      'blog' => string 'helloworld:blog' (length=15)   # from 0 ( new )
      'blogb' => string 'helloworld:blog' (length=15)  # from 1 ( new )
      'more' => string 'helloworld:Nojs' (length=15)   # from 2 ( new )
```

1. when the key is different = append
2. when the key is same = check important level get one highest level

question **what is the best way we can merge multiple into array but something like this?**

thanks for looking in

Adam Ramadhan

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this

```
$array1 + $array2 + array3;
```

Unlike `array_merge()`, the one with the most importance goes first, and numeric keys are respected.

If, like in your question, you are merging array elements in the same array, you can do

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $value) { $result += $value; }
```

Comment: wow dont know we can do that + + + how does that work? i dont see any php docs referring to this.

Comment: It's one of the more useful yet underused operators in PHP. http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Comment: awesome, how about reversing it?

Comment: just do `array_reverse($array);` before the `foreach`

Comment: Didn't know that either - really great and helpful answer!

Answer (score 1):

Just use [array_merge](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php) with your three arrays as parameters. The most important one should be the last one, so `array_merge($array2, $array1, $array0)` should work fine. The numeric keys might make a problem, though:

> If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

You might consider converting them to strings.

Comment: its on one array, how can we split them to merge them ?

Comment: You mean your initial arrays are inside a large array? You could try something like this: `$result = array(); array_merge($result, $array[2], $array[1], $array[0]);`, or something dynamic if you have more than three importance levels.

Answer (score 1):

```
$new_array = array();

 foreach($old_array as $level => $key_array) {
   foreach($key_array as $key => $value) {
     if(!isset($new_array[$key])) {
       $new_array[$key] = $value;
     }
   }
}
```

This will only work, if the "old" array is sorted by importance like in your example.