# append key array to an array value

Tags: php, arrays, logic

```
array
  'strongfruit' => 
    array
      apple => string 'say:helloworld'
      banana => string 'say:omgdude' 
      grape => string 'say:dope' 
      alienfruit => string 'say:ganja' 
  'weakfruit' => 
    array
      apple => string 'say:helloworld'
      banana => string 'say:omgdude'
      grape => string 'say:dope'
      orange => string 'say:yeahdude' 
  'moreweakerfruit' => 
    array
      apple => string 'say:helloworld'
      anotheralienfruit => string 'say:yeahhellyeah'
  (etc)
```

to be something like

```
array
      apple => string 'strongfruit:say:helloworld' ( from strong )
      banana => string 'strongfruit:say:omgdude'  ( from strong )
      grape => string 'strongfruit:say:dope'  ( from strong )
      alienfruit => string 'strongfruit:say:ganja' ( from strong )
      orange => string 'weakfruit:say:yeahdude' ( from weak)
      anotheralienfruit => string 'moreweakerfruit:say:yeahhellyeah' ( from weakeretc)
```

yesterday i ask about [joining arrays, preserving different value, pick one if same. with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6885243/joining-arrays-preserving-different-value-pick-one-if-same-with-php)

heres how we join them to get the order;

```
$result = array();
foreach ($array as $value) { $result += $value; }
```

the different **is how can we append the key to a value in an array?**.

Comment: How do you want to handle the fruit that appear under multiple keys (i.e. `apple`)? Should the ones after the first encountered be thrown away?

Comment: get it from the strong fruit. others should not be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$newarray = array();

foreach ($array as $type => $fruit) {
    foreach ($fruit as $fruitname => $string) {
        //if the fruit is not already in the new array
        if (!isset($newarray[$fruitname])) {
            $newarray[$value] = $type . ':' . $string;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: wheres the $value come from? do you mean `$newarray[$fruitname] = $type . ':' . $string;`